# Why is $\prod\limits_{p\le Y}\left(1+\frac{1+2e}{p}\right)\le(\log Y)^{10}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

> Why is $\prod\limits_{p\le Y}\left(1+\frac{1+2e}{p}\right)\le(\log Y)^{10}$

Can I bring $(1+2e)$ to the exponent and write $\prod\limits_{p\le Y}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1+2e}$ which is lesser than $7$, so is $\prod\limits_{p\le Y}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\le (\log Y)$ ?

Well In fact I should replace ''$\le$'' by $\ll$ but I think it is still true.

**Edit**: $p$'s are primes, Yes

Comment: So your product is over all prime numbers less than or equal to $Y$ ?

Comment: Just an idea, assuming the product is over primes. Taking log gives
$$
\log\left(\prod_{p \leq Y} (1+\frac{1 + 2e}{p}) \right) = \sum_{p\leq Y} \log(1+\frac{1 + 2e}{p})  \leq  \sum_{p\leq Y} \frac{1 + 2e}{p} = (1+2e) \sum_{p\leq Y} \frac1p
$$
Where the last sum is know to behave like $\sim \log\log(Y)$.

Comment: @Zubzub Thanks, I think your idea works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the log:
$$
\log \left( \prod_{p \leq Y} (1+ \frac{1+2e}{p}) \right) = \sum_{p \leq Y} \log( 1+ \frac{1+2e}{p}) \overset{(*)}{\leq}  \sum_{p \leq Y} \frac{1+2e}{p} = (1+2e) \sum_{p \leq Y} \frac{1}{p}
$$
$(*)$ Since $\log(1+x) \leq x, \ \forall x$

And the last sum is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) to be asymptotic to $\sim \log \log Y$.

Since $1+2e < 10$ we have the claim.